Running Linux and Windows container on Amazon ECS cluster
I have a few .NET microservices, and a couple of them are developed using the .NET Framework. I'm planning to host everything on an ECS cluster. I'm new to Amazon ECS, and I saw a blog article from Amazon stating that ECS Fargate now supports Windows containers. Is it feasible to host both Linux and Windows containers on the same ECS cluster?

If you are using Fargate deployments, then yes it is feasable, since each task runs on its own isolated environment with no real relation to any other tasks in the cluster. But also, if you are using Fargate, then there is no extra charge for more clusters, so it isn't really a concern either way.

@MarkB Did you ever try this scenario? I tried to run Windows and Linux container with in a single ECS cluster but it's not working as expected.

I have never had any reason or desire to run Windows containers. I don't see why it wouldn't work in the same cluster if you are only using Fargate deployments. Although like I said before, there is also no reason not to split them into multiple clusters if you are using Fargate. If something isn't working as expected, you should add the actual details of that to your question.
